# Excel graph showing customer representation based on size of different businesses

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I would like to represent in a graph the percentage of A, B and C customers in each business unit, taking into account the size of the BU (on the X axis).

```
         Sales      % A      % B      % C
        (kUSD)     Cust     Cust     Cust
BU A    1 000       10       50       40
BU B      100       40       40       20
BU C      500       20       30       50
```

Can you help me?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Did something not work?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create an intermediate table where each Customer Pct is weighted against the Business Unit Size giving you the graph you need:

[image: Chart]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I was not clear enough.

Comment: No problem, if you still need this clarify it and i'll (and lots of others) will give you a hand.